# My JAR doesnt work as when launched by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jar, ram

My program uses large text files (45MB) to operate and runs fine in eclipse. After being exported into a jar, it does not work properly when accessing the large source files. There are no problems with small files (300kB)

Eclipse: freezes for 10 seconds and then is ready with the file loaded.

Jar: Freezes for 5 seconds and nothing happens.

What can I change about the JAR to function properly?

EDIT:

```
public String [] RetreiveTokens(){
    String path = Main_Win.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    String decodedPath = null;
    try {
        decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String FileName=decodedPath+"languages/D3.txt";//LangPath+SourceFileLists.get(i);

    String content = null;
    boolean DictCC = false;
    int ContentsAddress=0;
    try {

        BufferedReader fin;

        String lineFromFile="";
        try {
            fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            //System.out.println("cc");
            lineFromFile = fin.readLine();
            lineFromFile=lineFromFile.substring(3);
            if(lineFromFile.substring(0,1).equals("#")){
                DictCC=true;
                for(ContentsAddress=0; fin.readLine().length()>0; ContentsAddress++);
                ContentsAddress+=2;
                //System.out.println(ContentsAddress);
            }
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(lineFromFile);
        //if(!DictCC){
        content = new Scanner ( new File (FileName), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        //}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] tokens=null;
    //String[][] Words_1=new String[2][32];;

    if(!DictCC){
        content=content.substring(1);
        content=content.replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
        tokens = content.split("\r\n");
    }
    else {
        content = content.split("\r\n")[ContentsAddress];
        tokens = content.split("    ");
    }

    for (int t=0; t<tokens.length; t++){
        if(tokens[t].contains("\n")){
            int index = nthOccurrence(tokens[t], '\n', 0);
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].substring(index);
        }
        if(tokens[t].contains("[")){
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replace(" [", "[");
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replace("] ", "]");
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");
        }
        if(tokens[t].contains("<")&&tokens[t].contains(">")){
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replace(" <", "<");
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replace("> ", ">");
            tokens[t]=tokens[t].replaceAll("\\<.*\\>", "");
        }
        tokens[t]=tokens[t].replaceAll("[?¿!¡,.;/'{}]", "");
        tokens[t]=tokens[t].replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that the application freezes? Do you probably see any exception on console?

Comment: How do you run your application outside eclipse? Could you send the command line?

Comment: It seems you are trying to load files which *should be* bundled in your JAR. Is this correct?

Comment: AlexR: I run it by doubleclicking the runnable jar. this is not a console app and is operated inside a jFrame, by freezes I mean the jframe is "not responding". but that is to be expected on a single thread. I don't know how I can display exeptions when the app is run from runnable jar in windows. I'd appreciate some help here..

Comment: user71: I hate to disappoint you but no, this is not the case. The files actually must not be included. The path is correct though. As mentioned earlier, the issue persists only with really big files like 45MB big ones.

Comment: You could attach VisualVM to your application to get an idea of where it "freezes".

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is shortage of heap memory. You are running the applicaiton by double clicking of its jar, so `javaw` that does not have STDOUT and STDERR is used.

Open command prompt and run your application by typing `java -jar yourjar.jar` where `yourjar.jar` is actual path to your jar.

You will see `OutOfMemoryError`. Now you should increase the memory. Add parameter `-Xmx2048M` to your execution path, i.e.:

`java -Xmx2048M -jar yourjar.jar`

I hope this will help. If not find better number. Obviously this line means that your application will be able to use up to 2G of heap.

Now the question is "why do you need so much memory?" Try to review your code and see what's happens. Probably you read whole file into the memory? Do you need this? Etc.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Actually, the problem does not occur when I launch the application as so: java -jar yourjar.jar. The problem only happens upon direct launch by doubleclicking.

Comment: or typing just "yourjar.jar" in the cmd. I can't see any exception in the commandline, however.